# For what value(/s) of $\lambda$ , solution of the following Integral Equation does not exist?

Tags: integral-equations

> For what value(/s) of $\lambda$ , solution of the following Integral Equation **does not exist** ?$$y(x)=1+\lambda\int_0^1(1-3xt)y(t)\,dt$$

Let , $$y(x)=1+\lambda C_1-3\lambda xC_2$$where , $$C_1=\int_0^1(1+\lambda C_1-3\lambda tC_2)\,dt=1+\lambda C_1-\frac{3}{2}\lambda C_2$$

$$\implies(1-\lambda )C_1+\frac{3}{2}\lambda C_2=1$$

and $$C_2=\int_0^1t(1+\lambda C_1-3\lambda tC_2)\,dt=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\lambda C_1}{2}-\lambda C_2$$

$$\implies \frac{\lambda C_1}{2}-(1+\lambda)C_2=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Now , $$D(\lambda)=\left|\begin{matrix}1-\lambda & \frac{3\lambda}{2}\\\frac{\lambda}{2} & -(1+\lambda)\end{matrix}\right|$$We know if $D(\lambda)\not=0$ then the I.E. has unique solution and if $D(\lambda)=0$ then the I.E. has **either no solution or infinitely many solutions**.

Now $D(\lambda)=0$ gives $\lambda=\pm 2$.For , $\lambda=2$ we can not eliminate $C_1 ,C_2$. So in this case the I.E. has **infinitely many solutions**.

When $\lambda=-2$ then we can find $C_1$ and $C_2$..

> But I can not find the values of $\lambda$ for which solution **does not exist**

Comment: Quick remark : there exist an unique solution for $\lambda=0$ : $y(x)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\lambda =2$, we find that the system of equations

$$-C_1+3C_2=1$$

and

$$C_1-3C_2=-\frac12$$

has no solution. Thus, the integral equation has no solution  for $\lambda =2$.

When $\lambda =2$, we find that the system of equations

$$3C_1-3C_2=1$$

and

$$-C_1+C_2=-\frac12$$

has no solution. Thus, the integral equation has no solution for $\lambda =-2$.